# sorting an array of structures in vb

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I have made a simple quiz game where the user gets asked 10 questions and gets a resulting score out of 10. I am currently programming the the leaderboards and I would like to sort the scores from highest to lowest. I have used a structure to ceep the data together and a 1D array to store the data.

```
  Structure userData
        Dim userName As String
        Dim score1Text As Integer
        Dim score2Text As Integer
        Dim score3Text As Integer
        Dim average As Integer
    End Structure

    Dim users(99) As userData
```

how do I sort the arrays by score and still keep the structure together?

Comment: the structure will "stay together" if you just assign one position to another. for example "users(0) = users(1)" will assign ALL user data from position 1 to position 0

Comment: I assume you want to sort the users by average score?  Why are the scores named "score1Text" when they're not text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement IComparable on your UserData class (make it a class, not a Structure)

```
Public Class UserData : Implements IComparable(Of UserData)
    Public Property userName As String
    Public Property score1 As Integer
    Public Property score2 As Integer
    Public Property score3 As Integer
    Public Property average As Integer ' I'd make this Double or something, but this is what you had.

    Public Function CompareTo(other As UserData) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of UserData).CompareTo
        If other Is Nothing Then Return 1
        Return average.CompareTo(other.average)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then somewhere else...

```
    Dim users As New List(Of UserData)
    ' Fill in users somehow...

    users.Sort()
```